# Subselect causes a join for each selected field

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a query with a subselect, and each additional field added to the subselect causes an extra join to the same table. I've reduced it a bit for posting here by removing `Where()` clauses, but the result is the same.

```cs
DbContext.Customer
    .Select(item => new
    {
        ID = item.Id,
        Name = item.NameCompany,
        BaseAddress = item.Customer_Address
            .Select(child => new
            {
                Street = child.Address.Street,
                Number = child.Address.Number,
                PostalCode = child.Address.PostalCode,
                City = child.Address.City
            })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Select(item => new
    {
        item.ID,
        item.Name,
        item.BaseAddress.Street,
        item.BaseAddress.Number,
        item.BaseAddress.PostalCode,
        item.BaseAddress.City
    })
    .First();
```

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[NameCompany] AS [NameCompany], 
[Element1].[Street] AS [Street], 
[Element1].[Number] AS [Number], 
[Element1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
[Element1].[City] AS [City]
FROM  [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Limit1].[AddressId] AS [AddressId], 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent3].[Street] AS [Street], 
    [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent4].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id2], 
    [Extent5].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
    [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id3], 
    [Extent6].[City] AS [City]
    FROM      (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent2].[AddressId] AS [AddressId]
        FROM [dbo].[Customer_Address] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[CustomerId] ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent3] ON [Limit1].[AddressId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent4] ON [Limit1].[AddressId] = [Extent4].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent5] ON [Limit1].[AddressId] = [Extent5].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent6] ON [Limit1].[AddressId] = [Extent6].[Id] ) AS [Element1]
```

Can I change my query to make it join once? Or is this possibly a bug in EF?

Comment: EF is such a pig. Formulate an explicit join.

Comment: @usr That means not using navigation properties, and (in my case) not using fluent syntax. The times I've tried `Join()` I always end up with something looking terrible. Not sure if it's even possible to write elegant an `Join()`.

Comment: I recommend that you use query expressions. That makes a lot of the pain go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is/was a bug. The current nightly of EF 6 produces much a much saner query. (The current beta, 6.0.0-beta1 still has this bug).

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[NameCompany] AS [NameCompany], 
    [Limit1].[Street] AS [Street], 
    [Limit1].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Limit1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
    [Limit1].[City] AS [City]
    FROM  [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent3].[Street] AS [Street], 
        [Extent3].[City] AS [City], 
        [Extent3].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
        [Extent3].[Number] AS [Number]
        FROM  [dbo].[Customer_Address] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[AddressId] = [Extent3].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[CustomerId] ) AS [Limit1]
```

Comment: With EF you can never be so sure which perf defects are bugs and which ones are by design.